# meaning for a differential form to be well defined

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have to show that 2-form ω= sin α dα ∧ ds is well defined on the phase space of an ellipse which can be topologically seen as a cylinder  with α∈(0,π) the angle of an oriented line going inwards and s∈ℝ/Lℤ the arc-length parameter. How can I proceed to prove that the 1-forms are well defined ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808874/what-does-it-mean-for-a-differential-form-to-be-well-defined-on-a-manifold/2778086?noredirect=1#comment5729377_2778086

Comment: I have found this topic but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: If you have global coordinates $(s,\alpha)$ on your $2$-dimensional manifold, there is nothing to check. My question would be why this description is the phase space of the ellipse (which to me means the cotangent bundle).